# How to calculate the interior angles total from giving 4 points in order?

Tags: objective-c, algorithm

I am using objective-c, and I would like to calculate the interior angles total, with giving 4 points in order. Is objective-c have these kind of maths library to do so ? Thanks.

Comment: As objective-c is a superset of c language you can use all standard maths functions, e.g. asin function.

Comment: Will it not be 360 degrees always?

Answer (score 2):

It is 180*(n-2), where n is the number of sides (=number of vertices) of the polygon.

Reference is [here](http://www.mathopenref.com/polygoninteriorangles.html).

Comment: This assumes it *is* a polygon. The reason for calculating the angles may be to see if it is, rather than having say, three of four points in a straight line(not that there aren't better ways to do that, but...).

Comment: @Geobits This relation holds even if you have 3 collinear points. In fact, it holds even if *all* of the points are collinear. Say you have *n* points on a line. The two end points make angles of 0 degrees with their neighbors. The remaining (n-2) points make angles of 180 degrees with their neighbors.

Comment: @beaker Ah, that makes sense. I wasn't accounting for the difference between 0/180.

Comment: @Geobits Yeah, so I'm a bit confused as to what the OP is trying to accomplish with this.

Answer (score 0):

Objective-C uses the standard C maths library maths.h.  This has the trig and sqrt functions you would be likely to need.

Answer (score 0):

I have just recently solved this problem in Java. There must be a good library for this. However if you are looking to calculate the angle between three points then you simply need to use the dot product of the two vectors which would be produced thus for

```
x_1, y_1, x_2, y_2, x_3, y_3
```

define

```
a_x = x_2 - x_1
a_y = y_2 - y_1
b_x = x_3 - x_2
b_y = y_3 - y_2
```

Then

```
dot_product = a_x * b_x + a_y * b_y
```

This allows you to calculate the value of cos_theta via the relation

```
cos_theta = dot_product / sqrt((a_x * a_x + a_y * a_y) * (b_x * b_x + b_y * b_y))
```

When you calculate the inverse cos of cos_theta you will get the smallest of the two possible solutions. I.e the values which are lass than or equal to 180 degress or PI radians.

I am not sure what you mean by the sum of the interior angles but if you sum the values derived from the above algorithm I think you will get what you want.

If you need to get the "angles on the left" or "the angles on the right" you will need to add a cross product to this algorithm.